# Unbound Array - PopBack with weird behavior

Tags: c++, data-structures

I wrote an unbound array, to practice some C++. But the popBack-method doesn't work properly. I'm just going to paste in my code, I hope it's not to much. Code is compiled with gcc (MacPorts gcc47 4.7.1_1) 4.7.1. I would appreciate some help. Thanks :)

**unbound_array.hpp**

```
#ifndef _unbound_array_h_
#define _unbound_array_h_

#include <iostream>

namespace datastructures
{

template <typename T>
class UnboundArray {

private:
    int beta;
    int alpha;
    int w;
    int n;

    //T data[];
    T *data;

    auto reallocate(const int size) -> void;

public:
    UnboundArray(): beta(2) {
        alpha = 4;
        w = 1;
        n = 0;
        data = new T[w];
    }

//  void pushBack(T& element);
    auto pushBack(T element) -> void;
    auto popBack() -> T;
    auto operator [](const int& b) -> T&;
};  

    template <typename T>
    auto UnboundArray<T>::pushBack(T element) -> void {
        if (n == w) {
            reallocate(beta * n);
        }
        data[n] = element;
        n++;
   }

    template <typename T>
    auto UnboundArray<T>::popBack() -> T {
        n = (n == 0) ? 0 : (n - 1);
        if ((alpha * n <= w) && n > 0) {
            reallocate(beta * n);
        }
        return data[n];
    }

    template <typename T>
    auto UnboundArray<T>::operator [](const int& b) -> T&{
        return data[b];
    }

    template <typename T>
    auto UnboundArray<T>::reallocate(const int size) -> void {
        int idx = n;
        w = size;
        T *array = new T[w];
        for (int i = 0; i < idx; ++i) array[i] = data[i];
        delete[] data;
        data = array;
        std::cout << "Reallocation. #elements: " << (n + 1) 
        << " new size of UnboundArray: " << w << std::endl;
    }

} // datastructures
#endif
```

**test.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "unbound_array.hpp"


using namespace datastructures;

int main() {
    int num = 25;

    std::cout << "Test of datastructures" <<std::endl;
    UnboundArray<int> a;
    for (int i = 0; i < num; ++i) {
        std::cout << "Adding "<< i <<" to UnboundArray." << std::endl;
        a.pushBack(i);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < num; ++i) {
        std::cout << "array[" << i << "] = "<< a[i] << std::endl;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < num; ++i) {
        std::cout << "Popping " << a.popBack() << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**output**

Adding (with resizing) works fine, also does operator[]. Just popBack troubles me.

```
Popping 24
Popping 23
Popping 22
Popping 21
Popping 20
Popping 19
Popping 18
Popping 17
Popping 16
Popping 15
Popping 14
Popping 13
Popping 12
Popping 11
Popping 10
Popping 9
Reallocation. #elements: 9 new size of UnboundArray: 16
Popping 8
Popping 7
Popping 6
Popping 5
Reallocation. #elements: 5 new size of UnboundArray: 8
Popping 3
Popping 3
Reallocation. #elements: 3 new size of UnboundArray: 4
Popping 556531726
Reallocation. #elements: 2 new size of UnboundArray: 2
Popping -268435456
Popping 0
```

**EDIT**

I changed the code in reallocate.

```
template <typename T>
auto UnboundArray<T>::reallocate(const int size) -> void {
    w = size;
    T *array = new T[w];
    for (int i = 0; i < w; ++i) array[i] = data[i];
    delete[] data;
    data = array;
    std::cout << "Reallocation. #elements: " << (n + 1)
    << " new size of UnboundArray: " << w << std::endl;
}
```

it works now.

**EDIT2**

`reallocate()` can't be called twice with `beta * n`, in `popBack()` it has to be `w / beta`.
`popBack()` now returns return `data[--n]`. The array is no allocated with `malloc()`.
The functionality is there, I'm going to add some checks, but that's pretty much it. Thank you.

```
template <typename T, size_t ALPHA, size_t BETA>
auto UnboundArray<T, ALPHA, BETA>::pushBack(T& element) -> void {
        if (n == w) {
                reallocate(BETA * n);
        }
        data[n++] = element;
}

template <typename T, size_t ALPHA, size_t BETA>
auto UnboundArray<T, ALPHA, BETA>::popBack() -> T {
        if ((ALPHA * n <= w) && n > 0) {
                reallocate(w / BETA);
        }
        T ret = data[--n];
        data[n] = 0;
        return ret;
}

template <typename T, size_t ALPHA, size_t BETA>
auto UnboundArray<T, ALPHA, BETA>::operator[](const int& b) -> T& {
        return data[b];
}

template <typename T, size_t ALPHA, size_t BETA>
auto UnboundArray<T, ALPHA, BETA>::reallocate(const int size) -> void {
        w = size;
        T* array = (T*) malloc(sizeof(T) * w);
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) array[i] = data[i];
        free(data);
        data = array;
        std::cout << "Reallocation. #elements: " << n << " new max size of UnboundArray: " << w << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: You should note that using array-new for your container forces your type to be default constructible and assignable, and causes needless default-constructions for the "unused" elements. Separating memory allocation and object construction (like `std::vector` does) is a crucial design improvement.

Comment: I'm not sure if I got you right, but with C++11 and its new move semantic, isn't that problem obsolete (operator= (T&&)). I didn't use vector, because I know that it saves me (brain)work. I wanted to do things myself to improve my data-structures and C++ knowledge.

Comment: C++11 isn't magic. I'm talking about fundamentals of the C++ object model. A dynamic container shouldn't contain more elements than it does, but your version does have those hidden elements that serve no purpose. A properer solution is to manage memory and objects separately.

Comment: @jim810 Please mark an answer as correct if it is (with the tick underneath the vote marks) or rephrase your question if there was no answer that solved the problem so far.

Comment: The problem was my reallocate method (I went out of bounds). I fixed it as exposed in the edit above. Unfortunately there was no answer which propagated that idea.

Comment: If that was so you should write it as an answer and accept it. But as I understand the code I would rather say you did not go out of bounds but you stayed below by one, which did in turn not trigger the needed copy and you accessed an uninitialized value. Instead with your new code you really go out of bounds, but include the value you did not copy before, so it looks like it works but it could deliberately break later on because of this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `popBack` decreases the size of the array, possibly relocates, which does a copy with the shrinked size and then tries to read the last element of the old size (which was not copied). I would suggest you change your popBack to:

```
template <typename T>
    auto UnboundArray<T>::popBack() -> T {
        n = (n == 0) ? 0 : (n - 1);
        T result = data[n];
        if ((alpha * n <= w) && n > 0) {
            reallocate(beta * n);
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Also I would throw an exception when popBack is called on an empty array.

**After the OPs edit**

The problem I mentioned is in some ways solved by the edit, but there are still flaws:
`reallocate` is always called with `beta * n` so inside reallocate `size = 2 * n`. As data will hold `n` elements it will end up reading twice as much data as is there. This could trigger access violations so you should consider your code as unsafe as long this is present. Instead the copy method should only read as much as is there (n elements). Of course this takes as granted that n always holds the correct number of elements in the array, so it must not be changed before `reallocate` is called.

Comment: Thank you! ...I almost forgot about my little project. I made some changes in edit2